# For a batch of pdf files in a directory, using Python find if there's a landscape page and rotate it to portrait

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to rotate any page in landscape to portrait in a batch of pdf files within a directory using Python. This is my code, while the landscape to portrait works but it duplicates pages n number of times. Help please.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
from os import listdir
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

input_dir = r"C:\Users\.......directory....\\"
output_dir = r"C:\Users\.......directory....\\"

for x in listdir(input_dir):
    if not x.endswith(".pdf"):
        continue
        
    reader = PdfReader(input_dir + x)
    writer = PdfWriter()
    for page in reader.pages:
        
        #Convert all pages to potrait
        numofpages = reader.numPages
        numrotated = 0 

        for pagenum in range(numofpages):
            page = reader.getPage(pagenum)
            mb = page.mediaBox
            if (mb.upperRight[0] > mb.upperRight[1]) and (page.get('/Rotate') is None):
                page.rotateCounterClockwise(90)
                numrotated = numrotated + 1
            writer.addPage(page)
            
    with open(output_dir + x, "wb") as pdf_out:
        writer.write(pdf_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. was duplicating the loop.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
from os import listdir
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

input_dir = r"C:\Users\....directory...\\"
output_dir = r"C:\Users\....directory...\\"

for x in listdir(input_dir):
    if not x.endswith(".pdf"):
        continue
        
    reader = PdfReader(input_dir + x)
    writer = PdfWriter()
    numofpages = reader.numPages
    numrotated = 0 

    for pagenum in range(numofpages):
        page = reader.getPage(pagenum)
        mb = page.mediaBox
        if (mb.upperRight[0] > mb.upperRight[1]) and (page.get('/Rotate') is None):
            page.rotateCounterClockwise(90)
            numrotated = numrotated + 1
        writer.addPage(page)
            
    with open(output_dir + x, "wb") as pdf_out:
        writer.write(pdf_out)
```